# Set current date from datepicker on textfield

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I'm setting a datepicker on a textfield. For that this is what I've written..(in `viewDidLoad`)

```
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(AddDetailsViewController.theDatePickerValueChanged(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
    dateTimeTextfield.inputView = datePicker
```

And outside `viewDidLoad` I have the function `theDatePickerValueChanged` given like so...

```
@objc func theDatePickerValueChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .medium
    formatter.timeStyle = .medium
    dateTimeTextfield.text = formatter.string(from: sender.date)
}
```

But now what happens is when I tap on the textfield, the datePicker comes up. But if I want the current date to be set on the textfield, then I have to move forward or backward from the current date on the datePicker and then again return to that current date.

But what I want is when the datePicker comes up, the current date on it should be directly set on the textfield without me requiring to go forward or backwards from the current date. How can I achieve this...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement text field delegate method `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` and in that delegate method you need to do like this...

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

  if dateTimeTextfield.text!.isEmpty {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .medium
    formatter.timeStyle = .medium
    dateTimeTextfield.text = formatter.string(from: Date())
  }
  return true
}
```

Don't forgot to set `dateTimeTextfield.delegate = self`.

Comment: Nice to hear that I could help.

Comment: Sure @Krunal. Have given an upvote to everyone..Thanks guys..:)

Answer (score 0):

Implement `UITextFieldDelegate` method `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` and call your function `theDatePickerValueChanged` like below:

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    if dateTimeTextfield.text!.isEmpty {
        theDatePickerValueChanged(sender: UIDatePicker())
    }
    return true
}
```

Set `dateTimeTextfield.delegate = self` in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: @bwv Yes it is but you can just review code. Shorter answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Set UITextFieldDelegate and use `textFieldDidBeginEditing`.

```
//Set delegate
dateTimeTextfield.delegate = self


// UITextFieldDelegate method
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> void {

  if textField.text == nil || textField.text!.isEmpty {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .medium
    formatter.timeStyle = .medium
    textField.text = formatter.string(from: Date())
  }

}
```